# Firefox looks different and seems slower

Tags: windows-7, firefox

I just installed windows 7 64 bit edition and firefox looks different. Before I was running windows xp pro and I think I had the latest version of firefox( I know for sure I had firefox 3.5 but not sure if I had firefox 3.5.2).

Now while working on my site I find it loads up so slow. I don't know why its running so slow since it's off local host. On Xp it use to be almost instant and now it takes like 10-20 seconds to load up on local host.

So I don't understand this slow down.

I also noticed that the disabled text-boxes on my site look different. Before they where all nicely grayed out now they look more like Ie's text-boxes where you can't tell if they are disabled or not till you try to click in them.

Thanks

like check out this from w3c school. If I where on XP the 2nd textbox would have a gray shading but it does not have it any more.

http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_input_disabled

Comment: Have you checked another browser, maybe just pop open IE and point it at localhost?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firefox chose to implement [different skins for different OSes](http://www.downloadsquad.com/2007/10/21/firefox-3-goes-native-native-skins-for-vista-xp-and-os-x/) - so possibly the difference you are seeing is the Vista/7 skin rather than the XP skin.

Comment: That's Windows 7 styling, not Firefox. Windows 7 doesn't turn disabled text box to gray (using Aero... Only the border and text is gray).

Comment: Yup, it depends on the OS. It's done to have a better OS integration; that's why both Firefox and all the page elements (buttons, comboboxes, checkboxes, text fields) look slightly different

Comment: Can I change that back? Without disabling aero? Like for me that should be the standard of how disabled textboxes should be. You know right away that they are disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 7 just gives a transparency at the top title bar?. Is that what u r considering looking different? Maybe u should scan for [malware](http://malwarebytes.org/).

Comment: No I am talking about textbox on webpages. They don't look like they use too. I doubt I have malware after a clean format.

Answer (score 0):

That and clear your history, wipe the cache and don't remember saved form data, all will help. 
And of course check your addons

Comment: I have far less plugins then I did when on Xp since I been too lazy to install them all.

Comment: That? what that?

Answer (score 0):

you dou know that [**Firefox for Windows x64**](http://wiki.mozilla-x86-64.com/Firefox:Download) is available?

Comment: No plugins?

More specifically, no Flash. Whilst sometimes a blessing it's more hassle than it's worth :)

Comment: Ya not worth it I need my plugins and probably flash too.

Comment: Without plugins, I'd hardly consider Firefox Firefox.

Comment: Exactly, I tried this, its not Firefox its Shiretoko or something, and Plugins don't work with it..